# Firebase avoid CORS being removed after redirect

Tags: firebase, cors

I have a Firebase function with CORS enabled, when I call it from AJAX from my website with the firebase domain it works, however, I have set up a custom domain in Firebase hosting and that redirect to the function domain, after trying it I experienced some problems due the CORS header being removed on the redirect, but how I implement a CORS header in a firebase hosting domain that is a redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use a rewrite instead a redirect, here are the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#directing_hosting_requests_to_your_function

and a example firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
"public": "public",

// Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "/bigben", "function": "bigben"
} ]
  }
 }
```